# Writing lines to a CSV using R

Tags: r, output

I have some R code there I am attempting to write a header in csv format then follow it up with data:

```
HeaderTXT <- paste("Year","Location","Type","Df","Sum Sq","Mean Sq","F value","Pr(>F)",sep=",")
capture.output(HeaderTXT,file = paste(csvdir,"SASlm-glmRowCol",Year,Location,".txt",sep=""))
stderr<-paste(Year,Location,"STD",x4$STD$ANOVA[[2]][[1]],x4$STD$ANOVA[[5]][[1]],x4$STD$ANOVA[[8]][[1]],x4$STD$ANOVA[[11]][[1]],x4$STD$ANOVA[[14]][[1]],sep=",")
capture.output(stderr,file = paste(csvdir,"SASlm-glmRowCol",Year,Location,".txt",sep=""),append = TRUE)
```

what happens however is I get a file like this below. With a [1] I do not want and " I do not want
how can I eliminate this?

```
[1] "Year,Location,Type,Df,Sum Sq,Mean Sq,F value,Pr(>F)"
[1] "2019,Preston,STD,72,32.4222222222223,0.450308641975309,NA,NA"
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what is wrong with the `write.csv()` or `writeLines()` functions?

Comment: If you replace `paste` with `cat` it might work but, in general, I agree with @teunbrand . You are probably far better off with creating a data frame and sending this through `write.csv`.

Comment: ahhh dammit of course write.csv was the right way to do it.